# Have I missed the point of pointers?

Tags: c

OK, sorry about the bad pun :P

I've [coded](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/blog/2010/09/an-old-classic-implemented-to-show-off-my-pointers-in-c/) the old trick of `HAL => IBM` in C. I've just read the first few pages in K&R reguarding them, and I thought it would be a good first play with them.

```
char evil[] = "HAL";
char *ptr = evil;   
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(evil); ++i, ++ptr) {             
    (*ptr)++;           
}   
printf("%s\n", evil); // IBM
```

My problem is, I have two variables incrementing, `i` and `ptr`, and something is telling me one of them is redundant (perhaps I'm still not *thinking* C well enough).

The only reason I use `i` is to determine if we have read to the end of the string. Is there any way to check the pointer to see if it has arrived at the end of the string?

### Update

Sorry for any confusion of the actual question. By *have I missed the point* I basically meant, why would I use a pointer when I needed an incrementing index to check the length as well. I could just use that index to subscript the right char from the array.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it is not necessary at all, `strlen(evil)` is *loop-invariant*, but you are evaluating it on each iteration. See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html for why that is a really bad idea.  Loop invariants should be evaluated outside the loop and assigned to a variable that is then tested rather than evaluating the invariant expression repeatedly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could as well write

```
for (char *ptr = evil; *ptr != '\0' ; ++ptr)
```

Comment: In C99, it is good to remember. Some compilers require an additional switch to go enable C99 mode.

Comment: Using `NULL` for comparison here, looks weird to me. I am even not sure that this is correct to compare a `null pointer` to a `char`. Probably you meant `'\0'` or just `0`.

Comment: You are right, slight mishap there... aren't `'\0'` and `0` pretty much equivalent?

Comment: `*ptr!='\0'` is more correct. NUL and NULL are very different beasts though NULL degenerates to int whose value is 0 if it needs to and NUL (which is simply a char whose value is 0) gets promoted to int if it needs to. The comparison works by accident which is why I prefer the more explicit `'\0'`.

Comment: Yes I agree that '\0' is the most readable form as it tells exactly what is being compared, chars in this case.

Comment: Personally I prefer `0`. In C, character literals are ints, so it's not even technically true that chars are being compared. Even worse: what `'\0'` means is, "the integer value of the character whose integer value is 0". Bit round-the-houses for my taste. But then, I usually use `0` rather than `NULL`, as well. As far as the standard is concerned they are both null pointer constants, and all I need is a null pointer constant. If someone doesn't know whether the variable I'm comparing to is int/pointer/char they're beyond my help, they need to to check the definition ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Why don't you just use `*ptr` as the loop condition without any comparisons? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: sometimes I do, it depends on context. But I'm more likely to write `*ptr != 0` in a loop condition than I am to write for example `if (*ptr != 0)`, because `for` loops in C tend to look like "spam spam spam" unless you write *something* else in there ;-) I think what I meant in that comment, though, is that *if* I want a literal for the ASCII nul character, then I prefer `0` to `'\0'`. Especially so in C since they have the same type. In C++ `'\0'` is a `char`, so at least they're giving us something in return for all that punctuation.

Answer (score 6):

I typed the question, re-read it, and then realised something very obvious I had overlooked!

```
char evil[] = "HAL" 
char *ptr = evil;   
for (; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr) {                       
    (*ptr)++;           
}   
printf("%s\n", evil);
```

That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: You can make the for loop a little clearer by initializing ptr in it: `for (ptr = evil; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)`. Be careful though. A bad string (without a null terminator) will have your program happily stomping its way across your stack.

Answer (score 5):

You've figured out the correct implementation, but I would still like to make one point about your original code, which may give you a different way to think about such problems.

Your original solution may be even worse than you think, because its complexity is actually O(n^2), where n is the length of the string.  `strlen()` has a complexity of O(n), because it has to iterate over all the characters in the string until it finds `'\0'`.  So you have a loop that performs n iterations, and calls `strlen()` each time, resulting in the complexity of O(n^2).

At the very least you should call `strlen()` once before the loop, and cache the length of the string.  And, of course, you have the correct solution that does not call `strlen()` at all.

Comment: +1 thanks, I also realised I should probably cache the length of the string as well.

Answer (score 3):

In `C` strings end with `'\0'`. You can use that fact to stop the loop.

```
for (; *ptr != '\0' ; ++ptr) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: Well ... depends on what you think the question is: `Have I missed the point of pointers?` or `Is there any way to check the pointer to see if it has arrived at the end of the string?`

Answer (score 2):

The character pointed to will be `'\0'`. But be careful, misplacing the NUL byte can be a source of program crashes or security holes.

Comment: Ah, yes, after typing the question all out and going over it a few times, it clicked! Happens to me all the time here... Thanks for your answer, do you have any recommended further reading as to why it may be a security hole? I'm still very fresh to C.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `strlen(evil)` is inefficient. Instead of relying on `strlen`, use the same thing that makes `strlen` stop: the null terminator:

```
for (char *ptr = evil; *ptr; ++ptr) {             
    (*ptr)++;           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:

```
char evil[] = "HAL";
*(int*) evil += 65793;
printf("%s\n", evil);
```

Comment: Well, it's certainly more evil. Try it on a 16-bit micro, see how far you get ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking about evil:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char evil[] = "HAL";
    char *ptr;

    // Increment the pointer and its content in the same expression
    // Just to be really evil

    for (ptr = evil; *ptr != '\0'; ++*(ptr++)) { }

    printf("%s\n", evil);
}
```

Comment: I thought I could do that, but I reckoned readability might have suffered! Still, good to know I can so +1

Comment: Yes readability does suffer and you should NOT do this. It is an example of being **EVIL**

Comment: Evil-wise, I was thinking: `while ((*ptr++)++); --*--ptr;`. Or something like that, I haven't tested it for the obvious reason that if I did, I would have to kill myself.